# Writing trigger on one table1 to update table2 and trigger on table2 to update table1

Tags: sql-server

I have two services and I want to keep sync in DB tables, So If service1 update table1 then I want to update table2 as well. And If service2 update table2 then I want to update table1 as well.

Can I write a trigger on table1 to update table2 and again a trigger on table2 to update table1? Will this create a loop?

Comment: There are no way to link one trigger to two tables unless you create an updatable view which hides both tables map all application code to work with this view. But this solution only useful if you on the start of developing new application from scratch.

Comment: It doen't seem like the best design - either have 1 table or update both at the same time. But if you can't do that then you can add a check in the trigger and only update if the values are different, otherwise you could end up in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I write a trigger on table1 to update table2 and again a trigger
>   on table2 to update table1? Will this create a loop?

It depends on server option [nested triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option)

> The `nested triggers` option controls whether an AFTER trigger can
>   cascade. That is, perform an action that initiates another trigger,
>   which initiates another trigger, and so on. When nested triggers is
>   set to 0, AFTER triggers cannot cascade. **When nested triggers is set
>   to 1 (the default), AFTER triggers can cascade to as many as 32
>   levels.** INSTEAD OF triggers can be nested regardless of the setting of
>   this option.

But you can avoid cascading anyway writing this code in your trigger as the first statement:

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN;
```